# Airflow + Sentry - no information from dags/tasks

Tags: airflow, sentry

I am trying to start using sentry to grab information from airflow. I am using the newest version of airflow (from v1.10.6  sentry is integrated with airflow). However i am not able to get any information about the dag or task status.

I prepared some simple dag which should fail, but on sentry i don't receive anything. The connection is established becouse when i make some typo for example in imports, the error infomation is catched at sentry. For this example i used the `SequentialExecutor`

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.utils.trigger_rule import TriggerRule


from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago

from airflow import AirflowException


################################################################################
# dag

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': days_ago(2),
    'email': ['airflow@example.com'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 0,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(seconds=3),
}

dag = DAG(
    'debug_sentry',
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval=None,
)


################################################################################
# first_task

def _first_task_callable(*args, **kwargs):
    pass


first_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id='first_task',
    python_callable=_first_task_callable,
    provide_context=True,
    trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ONE_SUCCESS,
    dag=dag
)


################################################################################
# second_task_which_fails

def _second_task_which_fails_callable(*args, **kwargs):
    a = 1
    b = 0
    c = a / b

    return c

second_task_which_fails = PythonOperator(
    task_id='second_task_which_fails',
    python_callable=_second_task_which_fails_callable,
    provide_context=True,
    trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ONE_SUCCESS,
    dag=dag
)

################################################################################
# third_task

def _third_task_callable(*args, **kwargs):
    pass

third_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id='third_task',
    python_callable=_third_task_callable,
    provide_context=True,
    trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ONE_SUCCESS,
    dag=dag
)


################################################################################

first_task >> second_task_which_fails >> third_task
```

What i did wrong or i missed something in configuration at `airflow.cfg`?

```
[sentry]
sentry_dsn = https://<my_dsn>
```

Answer (score 0):

There was a recent fix to the Sentry integration in Airflow as per: https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/7232. Try updating airflow to this commit?